# want to change the code actionscript2 to actionscript3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

i am newbie to flash.i need to change the below actionscript code to actionscript 3.0 code.
i am currently working on drag and drop. so i want to duplicate the movieclip while dragging i found the code on internet but it is actionscript 2.0 so please convert it to as3. the **box** is a instance name of a **movieclip**.
the code blocks are:

```
var num:Number = 0

box.onPress = function(){

    num++


    duplicateMovieClip(box ,"box"+num, _root.getNextHighestDepth())

    _root["box"+num].startDrag();

}

box.onReleaseOutside = function(){

    trace(_root["box"+num])

    stopDrag();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want to use seperate .as file, follow this steps:

1- assign `AS linkage` to box movieClip (in library panel):

[image]

2- Select frame 1 on the timeline, and paste this code in the Actions panel:

```
var boxes:Array=[];
//var box:Box=new Box();
//addChild(box);
box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,generateBox);
function generateBox(e:MouseEvent):void{
    var newBox:Box=new Box();
    newBox.x = e.target.x;
    newBox.y = e.target.y;
    newBox.startDrag();
    newBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,stopD);
    newBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,startD);
    boxes.push(newBox);
    addChild(newBox);
}
function startD(e:MouseEvent):void{
    e.target.startDrag();
}
function stopD(e:MouseEvent):void{
    e.target.stopDrag();
}
```

Comment: thank you man i got what i want. but i want to drag the child boxes not to reproduce the child but just drag.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no duplicateMovieClip analog in AS3, so you'll have to create a Class for your box movieClip template. Let's say it will be called BoxTemplate. (You can google how to create Classes for your library object). Add a Class with this name and add this code (event subscription in the constructor and a private event listener). You'll get something like this:

```
package
{
    public class BoxTemplate
    {
        public function BoxTemplate()
        {
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);
        }
    }

    private function onMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        stopDrag();
    }
}
```

Leave your present instance of this symbol on the stage. This is your code in the frame:

```
import flash.event.MouseEvent

box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var newBox:BoxTemplate = new BoxTemplate();
    newBox.x = e.target.x;
    newBox.y = e.target.y;
    addChild(newBox);
    newBox.startDrag();
}
```

It will allow you to infinitely clone your boxes. Of course, you can add all of them in the array to keep the references.

Comment: thankyou kumokairo for your answer. but the code shows the error 1013: The private attribute may be used only on class property definitions. please help me to solve the error.

Comment: @user2622338 As I've said, you have to create a class BoxTemplate.as and put the top part of the code there. You're trying to paste it to the frame and that is why you get this error

Comment: i have created the BoxTemplate.as by class for library object myMC(movie clip name) and paste the first block of code there. i pasted the second block of code in frame. and still i get the error please help me to solve the error

Comment: @user2622338 please, upload your project files somewhere so I can take a closer look)

Comment: http://www.fileswap.com/dl/xgazggpWw/ i have uploaded my files please solve the error and let me know the correction